# BFS function correctness?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

The problem is to construct/find the solution to a peg solitare game using a bfs function. You are given a node containing a start state, from this state the node expands into more states(its childs). The function is supposed to stop, once a node containing the goal state is found.

```
public void search(){
    bfs.add(StartGoal);
while(!bfs.isEmpty()) {
    node = bfs.poll();  
    if(node.isGoal()){System.out.println("success"); return;}
    node.expand();
    for(MyNode m : node.childs){
        if(!m.isGoal()){
            m.setVisited();
            bfs.add(m);}}
        node.setVisited();
    }
```

The expand function, initiates the childs linkedlist and creates child nodes based on the next possible board states.

```
public void expand(){
    if(childs != null) return;//already expanded do nothing
    else{
    childs= new LinkedList<MyNode>();
    for(BoardState b: state.nextStates())
        childs.add(new MyNode(this, b));}   
}
```

I ran the code and improved it several times. Once the queue reaches size 3+ million, it crashes due to insufficient space. My question is: Will this eventually work? Is the code correct?

This is my first post so sorry if I suck at formatting the question nicely.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. I see two big bugs, or perhaps one big bug with two major consequences, and one small bug. There may be other bugs I can't see, and there are definitely other things to improve. The first bug is that

```
    if(!m.isGoal()){
        m.setVisited();
        bfs.add(m);}}
```

you specifically never add goal states to the queue.

The second bug is that you never test whether a node has been visited. This may be the same bug as the first one, because it looks like they may be fixable with the same fix:

```
if (!m.isVisited()) {
```

The third bug is that you only mark a node visited after processing its first child. You'll never mark a node visited if it has no children, and if it were possible for a node to have itself as a child, you would add the child to the queue before expanding the parent. This won't affect the correctness of your results, though it may affect your efficiency.